# Python Pandas dataFrame - Columns selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataFrame object train_df with say a column called "ColA" and a column "ColB". It has been loaded from a csv file with columns header using read_csv

I obtain the same results when I code:

`pd.crosstab(train_df['ColA'], train_df['ColB'])`

or

`pd.crosstab(train_df.ColA, train_df.ColB)`

Is there any difference in these 2 ways of selecting columns?

When I request to print the type it's the same : `pandas.core.series.Series`

Answer (score 0):

No difference

`pd.crosstab(train_df['ColA'], train_df['ColB'])` is recommended to prevent possible errors.

For example, if you have a column named `count` and if you type `train_df.count` it will give an error. `train_df['count']` won't give an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to select a single column, there is no difference between the two ways.

However, the dot notation doesn't allow you to select multiple columns, whereas you can use `dataframe[['col1', 'col2']]` to select multiple columns (which returns a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` instead of a `pandas.core.series.Series`).